Text outside the plot; how to add add a paragraph, selectively bold, and save plot with annotations
I am trying to edit text outside a plot, below the legend.  I've followed the instructions suggested here and I've been able to put together the following code
p <- ggplot(Amh2, aes(x=syllable, y=durZ, color=condition)) + 
  geom_boxplot(lwd=1) + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(text = element_text(size=15, family="Times New Roman")) + 
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size=13)) +
  xlab("syllable") +
  ylab("SDs from by-speaker mean") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=scales::pretty_breaks(n=7), limits=c(-3,3)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin=margin(t=5, r=0, b=0, l=0))) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin=margin(t=0, r=5, b=0, l=0))) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color="#000000", size=12, family="Arial")) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(color="#000000", size=12, family="Arial")) +
  theme(legend.position="right",
        legend.justification="center",
        legend.margin=margin(0,0,0,0),
        legend.box.margin=margin(0,0,0,-5)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#FF0000", "#000000"), labels=c("focus", "nonfocus")) +
  theme(legend.text = element_markdown(size=12, family="Arial")) + 
  theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
  annotate(geom="text", x=1, y=2.35, label="*", color="black", size=15) +
  annotate(geom="text", x=2, y=2.35, label="*", color="black", size=15) +
  annotate(geom="text", x=3, y=2.35, label="*", color="black", size=15) +
# Here is the relevant portion:
  theme(legend.position="right", plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,3,1),"lines")) +
  annotation_custom(grob = textGrob("A1-CV.CV"), 
                    xmin = 2, xmax = 12.5, ymin = -4.5, ymax = 3.2) +
  annotation_custom(grob = textGrob("B1-CV.CVC"), 
                    xmin = 2, xmax = 12.65, ymin = -4.5, ymax = 2.7) +
  annotation_custom(grob = textGrob("C1-CV.CVG"), 
                    xmin = 2, xmax = 12.65, ymin = -4.5, ymax = 2.2)

gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name=="panel"] <- "off"
grid.draw(gt)

Here is the plot it produces, with the "A1, B1, C1" text added beneath the legend.  (What I'm trying to do is add text to further expand on the x-axis labels.)
I have three questions from this, which I can't seem to figure out.

Is there a way to add a text box below the legend, such that I could have multiple lines of text that are left-aligned?  As it is, I've meticulously aligned the three annotations by adjusting their ymax and xmax, but it's not ideal.  Wrapping the text might also work, but it would be most ideal to control when it hops to the next line.

Is there a way to add selective bolding these annotations?  This post explains how to do it with regular annotate, but I can't figure out how to do it with annotation(custom).  I would like the first label, for instance, to be "A1-CV.CV".

Is there a way to save the whole plot, using something like ggsave?  I want to save the plot with no loss in quality, but it seems like ggsave doesn't pick up the added custom annotations – it just saves the base plot.


Here is some sample data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GYqeIboYIX7qzwwrL6AbnZ03mf5ljvGk/view?usp=sharing

Reminder for future questions: It would be easier to help you if you provide a minimal reproducible example including a snippet of your input data best shared using dput() or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset.

Here is one option to achieve your desired result more easily which uses a fake size legend to add your text annotations which does not requires any fiddling to set the positions and the alignment, makes it easy to use ggtext to style the text annotations (i.e. make parts bold) and finally gets rid of the unnecessary grid hacks (You can set clipping off using coord_cartesian(clip = "off").
Using some fake example data:
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

set.seed(123)

Amh2 <- expand.grid(
  syllable = c(paste0(LETTERS[1:3], 1), paste0(LETTERS[1:3], 2)),
  condition = c("focus", "nonfocus")
) |>
  cbind(durZ = rnorm(100 * 6 * 2))


p <- ggplot(Amh2, aes(x = syllable, y = durZ, color = condition)) +
  geom_boxplot(lwd = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 7), limits = c(-3, 3)
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("#FF0000", "#000000"),
    labels = c("focus", "nonfocus")
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    text = element_text(size = 15, family = "Times New Roman"),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 13),
    axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 5, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)),
    axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 5, b = 0, l = 0)),
    axis.text.x = element_text(color = "#000000", size = 12, family = "Arial"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(color = "#000000", size = 12, family = "Arial"),
    legend.position = "right",
    legend.justification = "center",
    legend.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 0),
    legend.box.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, -5),
    legend.text = element_markdown(size = 12, family = "Arial"),
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 3, 1), "lines")
  ) +
  xlab("syllable") +
  ylab("SDs from by-speaker mean") +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 1:3, y = 2.35, label = "*", color = "black", size = 15) +
  # Add annotations using a fake size legend and a geom_point
  geom_point(
    data = data.frame(
      label = c("A1-**CV**.CV", "B1-*CV*.CVC", "C1-**CV**.CVG")
    ),
    aes(size = label),
    x = NA, y = NA,
    key_glyph = "blank",
    inherit.aes = FALSE,
    na.rm = TRUE
  ) +
  guides(
    # Use order to set the order
    color = guide_legend(order = 1),
    size = guide_legend(
      order = 2,
      theme = theme(
        legend.text.position = "left",
        legend.text = element_markdown(hjust = 0)
      )
    )
  )

p
#> Warning: Using size for a discrete variable is not advised.
#> Warning: Removed 2 rows containing non-finite outside the scale range
#> (`stat_boxplot()`).



This works perfectly, thank you!  One question though -- is there a way to customize the order of the labels in the fake size legend, like with  scale_size_manual?  As it is, they appear alphabetically.

Also, I used the same code but the size labels appear further to the right than they do in your example, aligned with the "focus"/"nonfocus" text.  Any idea as to why they're not aligned below the red and black boxplot icons?

If it helps, I just edited my original post with a link to sample data.  When I use this data with the block of code you sent, I get the two issues I listed above.

Concerning the order: Make the vector of labels a factor with your desired order (or add scale_size_manual and set the limits=). Concerning the second question: Could you check your ggplot2 version. Mine is ggplot2 3.5.1. The theme= parameter which I use to put the legend.text on the left of the "blank" key was introduced in ggplot2 3.5.0 and will not work in older versions.

Excellent, this fixed both issues! I reinstalled ggplot2 and I was able to make the vector of labels a factor (the question in this post helped).
Thank you so much for your help!
